# Listing users with multiple parameters by Display name

Tags: powershell

So the task I'm facing seems harsh to me, I barely started using PowerShell too.
I need to create a detailed List of all users by their display name, which means it begins with " x- "
I need their details, including user creation date, enabled/disabled, last login date, and company
can you help a fellow beginner out?

Answer (score 1):

You should try googling and providing more information. It appears you have not completed any searching.

A simple "Get all users powershell" into google would bring you to `Get-ADUser`

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | Export-Csv "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\UserData.csv" -NoTypeInformation

# This gets all users in AD and all properties
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties *

# This will send those results to a CSV file on your desktop     
| Export-Csv "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\UserData.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I'm sitting here : Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like "*x-*"} *-Properties* | select Name,whenCreated,LastlogonDate,Compa ny,Enabled
The Syntax is not working when i try to filter the name, the rest is working properly, but i need to tighten the scope. I did do research, and i came up with this, however i'm not the best with the syntaxes

Comment: @VargaAttila Try `Get-ADUser -Filter "Name -like 'x-*'" -Properties Name, Created, LastLogonDate, Company, Enabled`

Comment: If the `x-` is the first part of their domain login, then you need to change `Name` to `SamAccountName`.